# Server Setup and management tool (akin to MacOS Server)

Tags: linux

Does a tool exist (for Linux) that allows you to setup services using a GUI akin to how MacOS Server worked?

For those unfamiliar, MacOS Server let you configure services such as HTTP, SMB, VPN, Wiki, etc, from a GUI. I'm wondering if something similar exists for Linux (any distro).

I hope a question like this is allowed.

Thank you.

-- edit --

MacOS Server lets you configure things such as:

- HTTP

  - Starting/Stopping
  - Enabling SSL
  - Enabling PHP
  - Creating hosts and their web root
  - Defining networks that have access
- VPN

  - Enabling/Disabling the service
  - Selecting users and their access
  - Defining the networks that have access
  - Picking the VPN type and setting the configurations on it

    - Shared Secret
    - Etc
- Wiki

  - Enabling/Disabling the service
  - Creating wikis
  - Managing users
- SMB/AFP

  - Enabling/Disabling the service
  - Defining mount points and who has access

There are other things that you can do but those are the most important to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a vendor-agnostic tool called 'webmin', which connects a web browser into an https 'server' -generally used within a single system system - to provide a GUI which provides rudimentary control, and also edits configuration files for various Servers.

But many Linux Distributions provide custom tools which are even more capable. openSUSE 'Yast' is the example with which I am most familiar (being a "Tumbleweed" user), and Mageia's 'MCC' ("Mageia Control Center") also has great reviews for usability.

My own system (openSUSE "Tumbleweed") is bleeding-edge experimental, and NOT suitable either a beginner or "Production" usage. Megeia, Mint, and the more stable openSUSE 'Leap' might be all be good candidates for you.

Arch and Manjaro native 'GUI' management is too limited for your needs - you would be using 'webmin' for most of your GUI control and configuration of Servers. Ubuntu might also be somewhat lacking in GUI "Server Control" features, even though it is friendly for end users. (I have not used Ubuntu, and really don't know what it offers.)

IMO, OpenSUSE 'Leap' (with 'YAST') and Mageia (with MCC, 'Mageia Control Center') are top candidates for you. The Classic Server, Red Hat/CentOS, also deserves a close look - but your question implies a need for more "friendly" and less "experienced"-oriented Distribution. (I have a RH Server, but use text editors + command line for nearly all management on that box.)

Mageia might be best for you. But take a look and choose whatever seems to fit your orientation best. You can switch Distros at a later time, if you change your mind. openSUSE and Mageia both offer live DVD's for try-outs. With **multiple** live-DVD/live-USB "tryout-outs", however, you need to make sure that they each have their own UserID, in order to avoid one Distro overwriting the other Distro with conflicting 'user configuration' settings.

[image: OpenSUSE 'Yast' screenshot]

Comment: I use webmin myself, but it's not without problems.  One problem, for example, is that when you use it to change network settings they can mess up your config (or changes will be overwritten) if you're using CENTOS or RHEL because they use network manager by default.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to give my question a few more days and if I don't get anything better I'll give you the bounty.

Comment: apocalysque: Thanks for that advisement! My openSUSE computers have an advantage there, in offering a choice between NM (good for laptops and other portable PCs), and management service called "Wicked" - configurable from either the GUI or command-line. I use 'Wicked' on my computers, because it's easily used in lower runlevels. (NM kinda wants runlevel=5, with a GUI.) All configurable from YAST.